# In vs studio python Print ("Welcome") it does not run when I type the file name

Tags: python, xcode, visual-studio, terminal

I used a simple code for python in my VS Studio. Print ("Welcome")  when I run it through the run button it works fine but when I want to run it through typing  the file name ( eg .\02_hello.py) and press enter it doesn't run and instead leave a blank line. I don't know what's wrong.please help

I want the python code to run through typing the file name in terminal window of vs studio just as it works fine when I use the run button to run code.    [image]

Comment: Whenever someone posts a literal screenshot of their code, especially one take with their phone, I feel they're just trolling StackOverflow. Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't trolling or something. I am a newbie here in StackOverflow I don't know how all these things work. The photo was more than 2mb so I took the screenshot to reduce the file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't telling the terminal what that python file should do. In default it opens the file in vscode. Try this:

```
python 02_welcome.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specific the python interpreter to run your code
try:

```
python ./02_hello.py
```

Comment: also try not to post a photo next time

Comment: The WIndows Python installations set up file associations so that entering the name should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have a file of that name on path.
also type :
`python .\02_welcome.py`